# How can I use the crate : “bech32-no_std” in rust？

Tags: rust

In Cargo.toml, I add the code:

```
[dependencies]
bech32-no_std = "0.7.3"
```

When I want to use it:

```
use bech32-no_std::{u5, CheckBase32};
```

This raised an error:

```
Syntax Error: expected BANGrust-analyzer
Syntax Error: expected `{`, `[`, `(`rust-analyzer
Syntax Error: expected SEMICOLONrust-analyzer
unresolved macro `self::no_std!`rust-analyzerunresolved-macro-call
```

This may be caused by no_std. It should be just a grammatical problem, but i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: In source code, hyphens in crate names have to be replaced with underscores. Will `use bech32_no_std::{u5, CheckBase32};` work?

Comment: You are right! Thank you very much!